# What's pgrp in this context?

Tags: ps, gdb

Quoted from [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9039).

> gdb puts the debugged process in its
>   own pgrp and sets the terminal to that
>   pgrp.  (Try e.g. ps j on the PIDs of
>   gdb and your program being debugged.)

And what does it mean by

> ps j on the PIDs of gdb and your program being debugged

does that mean `ps j PID`?

I don't get anything special from this though...

Basically I don't understand what that article is talking about,can anyone explain it in more great details?

Answer (score 3):

A “pgrp” is a [process group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group). `ps j` lists the process group ID (the column is called `PGID`). The PGID of a process is typically itself or its parent's process group, but can be arbitrarily set with `setpgid()`. Process groups control what processes receive job control signals. I think gdb moves the process to its own group so as to avoid having the process receive job control signals that would mess up gdb's control over the process.

The bug report is about using gdb with a program that uses [`sigwait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigwait.html). `sigwait` allows a process to receive a signal in an underhand way: instead of being delivered to the process in the usual manner, the signal is removed from the pending queue and `sigwait` returns. This is mainly useful to arrange for a signal to be always delivered to a particular thread: block the signal, but have a thread consume it by running `sigwait`.

Since the signal is not actually delivered to the process, `ptrace` sees nothing, and so gdb isn't notified that the process has underhandedly consumed the signal.

The debate in the bug report is about whether the kernel should be modified so that `ptrace` sees something when the signal is consumed through `sigwait`, or whether gdb should handle this situation differently. I don't know enough about this to take sides.

Comment: Do you understand the explanation in that bug that says it's not a bug?

Comment: @locale: I've expanded my answer, but deciding whether it's a bug or not is beyond my level of expertise. P.S. This is getting really into developper territory; I've recommended that your question be migrated to [so], and I recommend that you create an account there and associate it with your [sf] account.